# filamentphp make group of menu visible and invisible conditionally

Tags: laravel, filamentphp

I am using this filamentphp package https://github.com/phpsa/filament-authentication

It has a menu group 'authentication' with menus 'Role', 'Permission' and 'User'. I want to hide complete menu group with the menus conditionally.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done to solve the same problem:

Installed Spatie Permissions as per Spaties' documentation:

[Install Spatie Permissions on Laravel](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel)

After that, I installed Shield plugin to manage all the roles and permissions:

[Shield Plugin](https://filamentphp.com/plugins/bezhansalleh-shield)

With that in mind, with the permissions generated by Spattie you will get the **Policies**. Those are so important because are the filament resource permission settings. Ex: UserPolicy - Here you can handle how the roles could interact with the resource.

So, if you use Shield to create new role, enable the specific permissions and then use the policy to limit the access by role, like:

Then, you can achieve what you want.

`public static function viewAny(User $user): bool  { return $user->hasRole('admin'); }`

I hope it helps, I had to make a lot of research to understand it.